# how can we update one to one relationship models db data from django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

[image][image]i am new to django and i created onetoOneField relationship model with inbuilt User model of django but i cant figure out how can i update that model class table value.
My model

```
class category(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TYPES = [
        ("BASIC","BASIC"),
        ("PLUS","PLUS"),
        ("PRO","PRO")
    ]
    User_Type = models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=TYPES,default="BASIC")
    Product_Limit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Amount_Paid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Tried these 2 cases but getting some error

```
#key = category.objects.update_or_create(id=request.user.id,User_Type= request.user.category.User_Type,Product_Limit=2,Amount_Paid=request.user.category.Amount_Paid)
 user = request.user.category.update_or_create(Product_Limit=10)
```

Comment: Can you add the errors that you are getting in each case ?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: willl edit with images give me 1 minute

Comment: can u check it now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
category = Category.objects.filter(user=request.user).update_or_create(
    user=user, Product_Limit=10
)
```

This will make two SQL queries:

- First, Django will make a `SELECT ... FROM category WHERE user_id = ...`. As `category` and `user` has a one to one relationship, this should return 0 or 1 row.
- If the first query has no record, Django will make an `INSERT INTO category` query with `user_id=request.user.id` and `Product_Limit=10`, the other fields following the default values.
- If the first query has a record, Django will make a `UPDATE category SET user_id = ..., Product_Limit = ... WHERE user_id = ...` query to update the `Product_Limit` field.